# In what sense are the private and public aspects of the City of London corp one entity?

Tags: city-of-london

City funds function from tax revenue and are subject to FOIA and presumably so Judicial Review types of challenges.

City cash on the other hand functions privately and the two are apparently separately siloed off from each other.

But in which senses are these two entities the same? How are they connected to one another if the funds have such a wall between them?

Answer (score 0):

One sense in which they are the same is that they are both controlled by the City of London Corporation. See https://democracy.cityoflondon.gov.uk/documents/s162344/Citys%20Cash%20Annual%20Report%20Financial%20Statements%202020-21%20-%20ARM-FC.pdf:

> City’s Cash is a fund of the City of London Corporation
>
> ...
>
> City’s Cash is managed by committees of the City Corporation, with Membership of
> the committees drawn from the 25 Members of the Court of Aldermen and the 100
> Members of the Court of Common Council. Members of the Court of Aldermen and
> Court of Common Council are elected by registered voters (both residents and
> businesses) within the City of London. In determining appointments to
> committees, the Court of Aldermen and Court of Common Council will take into
> consideration, amongst other things, any particular expertise and knowledge of
> the Aldermen and Members.

Another way that they are the same is that neither the city's funds or the City's Cash are "entities." They are each funds of the city.

Comment: Certain operations/functions that draw from and remit to the two funds respectively seem to be carried out by different teams. In the sense they would seem to be different "sections" of the entity of the colc. I think entities could be used to describe these divisions.